# How do I solve the problem of inverted colors in OBS studio?

Tags: games, 18.10, colors, streaming, obs-studio

I tried to make a recording for gameplay of youtube and twitch but via obs but I found something very inconvenient.
The colors are all inverted ... (or fading, I have no idea)
I would like a help from you if possible
Ubuntu I'm using is the 18.10 obs is the 21.0.1
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a better solution than the most upvoted answer:

Double-click your Window Capture:

[image]

Select "Swap Red and Blue":

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In your scene, highlight the vidio source and choose "Filters" from the menu.

Choose the filter marked "Color Correction".  Inside the filter, slide the "Hue Shift" back and forth until the colors are correct.

[image]

Comment: I will try  that, if i success or not i comeback to tell you

Comment: Look, i found another tthink to change.
Change 
If I select the source, clicking on engine there will be an option unchecked

The checkbox "change Red to blue".is unchecked
This is strange, how a software turns this unchecked by default installation?

Comment: @Erikcht Interesting!  I don't think that is available for all sources - I don't usually see that on the video capture devices that I use, or the screen capture.  Just the window capture...

Answer (score 4):

I tried the fix suggested in a [comment by Erikcht](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122771/how-do-i-solve-the-problem-of-inverted-colors-in-obs-studio/1122834#comment1864540_1122834) and it corrected the problem of inverted colours:

Select the source and click on engine.

There will be a checkbox for **change red to blue** and changing this fixed the problem.